# Conditional Delivery Notice based on Time and Date in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time, woocommerce

I am trying to get a message together that will display a shipping notice depending on what time it is monday to thursday and friday to sunday.

If the customer orders before 12 o'clock (daytime) the order is shipped the same day, monday to thursday and delivered the next day.

If the customer orders after 12 o'clock monday to thursday the order will be prepared and shipped the day after, monday to thursday.

All orders made friday to sunday will be prepared and shipped on the following weekday (monday).

The code I am using does not do this and I am trying to understand how to make it work. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'next_day_delivery' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'next_day_delivery' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'next_day_delivery' );

    function next_day_delivery() {

        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
        $end_time         = mktime('12', '00', '00', '2018');
        $now_time         = strtotime("now");

        if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() > 0 ) && $now_time < $end_time {

        // print the information notice
        wc_print_notice( __( 'Order within $end_time - $now_time and get your order delivered tomorrow!', 'woocommerce' ), 'success' );
    }

else if wc_print_notice( __( 'Your order will be prepared and shipped on Monday.', 'woocommerce' ), 'success' );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some mistakes and missing things in your code. The following will display conditionally a custom shipping notice as defined in your question:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'next_day_delivery' );

function next_day_delivery() {
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return; // Exit

    // Set the time zone
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');

    // From Monday to Thursday
    $is_week_days  = in_array( date('w'), array( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) ) ? true : false;
    $end_time      = mktime('12', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
    $now_time      = time();
    $after_tomorow = date('l', strtotime('+2 days'));

    $dateDiff      = intval(($end_time - $now_time)/60);
    $diff_hours    = intval($dateDiff/60);
    $diff_minutes  = $dateDiff%60;
    $hours_label   = _n( 'hour', 'hours', $diff_hours, 'wooocommerce' );
    $minutes_label = _n( 'minute', 'minutes', $diff_minutes, 'wooocommerce' );


    if ( $end_time > $now_time && $is_week_days ) {
        // print the information notice
        $message = sprintf( __( '%s left to be delivered tomorrow!', 'woocommerce' ),
        $diff_hours.' '.$hours_label.' and '.$diff_minutes.' '.$minutes_label);
    }
    elseif ( $end_time <= $now_time && $is_week_days ) {
        $message = sprintf( __( 'Your order will be delivered this %s.', 'woocommerce' ), $after_tomorow );
    } else {
        $message = __( 'Your order will be prepared and shipped next upcoming monday and delivered on tuesday.', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    wc_print_notice( $message, 'success' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Wow, you are rally helping me out :) The only thing "missing" would be to print the time left to order. Example; it is monday and the time is 11. The message would include that there is only one hour left to make orders.

But I guess that would be a new question?
Either way, thank you very very much!

Comment: @WooDevil Updated displaying remaining hours and minutes

Comment: $after_tomorrow doesn't work. There is no setting for that. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @WooDevil I have added it back… I have removed a line by mistake.

Comment: yes, I noticed that and I back-tracked it. Thanks for re-adding it again.

Comment: How to translate week days another language ? its showing only english.