# Display how much is left before free shipping and Delivery Information in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, notice

Based on this answer: [Conditional Delivery Notice based on Time and Date in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062275/conditional-delivery-notice-based-on-time-and-date-in-woocommerce/53069761#53069761), I am getting a shipping message based on specific shipping coonditions.

Now I realized that I need to set the free shipping method in WooCommerce and doing so, I need to inform the customer about how much that remains until they get free shipping.

So, I found this code:

```
$total_cart = WC()->cart->total;
$limit_for_free_shipping = 99;

    if ($total_cart != 0 && $total_cart < $limit_free_shipping ) { 
        $difference = wc_price( round($limit_for_free_shipping - $total_cart, 2) );
        ?>
   
    <p class="spend_message" >
        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/shipping-icon.png"> <?php _e('If you spend another '); ?> <?php echo $diff; ?> <?php _e(', you will get '); ?> <strong><?php _e('FREE SHIPPING!'); ?></strong>
    </p>

<?php
    }
```

But I am having trouble getting this merged with the other message and turning it into a `<p>` tag instead of a `wc-notice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will merge both functionalities in one:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'next_day_delivery' );

function next_day_delivery() {
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return; // Exit

    // Set the time zone
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');

    // From Monday to Thursday
    $is_week_days  = in_array( date('w'), array( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) ) ? true : false;
    $end_time      = mktime('12', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
    $now_time      = time();
    $after_tomorow = date('l', strtotime('+2 days'));

    $dateDiff      = intval(($end_time - $now_time)/60);
    $diff_hours    = intval($dateDiff/60);
    $diff_minutes  = $dateDiff%60;
    $hours_label   = _n( 'hour', 'hours', $diff_hours, 'wooocommerce' );
    $minutes_label = _n( 'minute', 'minutes', $diff_minutes, 'wooocommerce' );
    $minutes_displ = $diff_minutes.' '.$minutes_label;
    $hours_display = $diff_hours.' '.$hours_label.' and ';
    $remain_time   = $diff_hours > 0 ? $hours_display . $minutes_displ : $minutes_displ;

    $cart_total    = WC()->cart->total;
    $limit_free    = 100; // Starting freee shipping amount
    $free_shipping = '';  // Initialising

    if ( $cart_total < $limit_free ) {
        $free_shipping =  sprintf(
            __('%s If you spend another %s you will get %s', 'woocommerce' ),
            '', // ' <img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/shipping-icon.png"> ',
            strip_tags( wc_price( round( $limit_free - $cart_total, 2 ) ) ),
            '<strong>' . __( 'FREE SHIPPING!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>'
        );
    } elseif ( $cart_total >= $limit_free ) {
        $free_shipping = '<strong>' . __( ' You get FREE SHIPPING!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>';
    }

    if ( $end_time > $now_time && $is_week_days ) {
        // print the information notice
        $message = sprintf( __( '%s left to be delivered tomorrow! %s', 'woocommerce' ), $remain_time, $free_shipping );
    }
    elseif ( $end_time <= $now_time && $is_week_days ) {
        $message = sprintf( __( 'Your order will be delivered this %s. %s', 'woocommerce' ), $after_tomorow, $free_shipping );
    } else {
        $message = __( 'Your order will be prepared and shipped next upcoming monday and delivered on tuesday.', 'woocommerce' ) . $free_shipping;
    }
    wc_print_notice( $message, 'success' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

[image]

**Update:** Removed hours when they are equal to zero:

[image]

> **To use a `<p class="my-custom>` html tag** instead of using the Woocommerce notice structure, replace:
>
> ```
> wc_print_notice( $message, 'success' );
> ```
>
> by:
>
> ```
> echo '<p class="my-custom>' . $message . '</p>';
> ```
>
> **You are done…**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Since it's still a notice and not a <p> tag, I'm wondering how to add a class to it so that I can style it.

Comment: cool, I'll see how it looks with a <p class=""> and try to merge it over from a notice (as mentioned in my question above) to a <p>. Thanks again!

I can make a new question if you like, but I'm just curious on how to remove the "0 hours" from the notice if only minutes remain? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: THANK YOU. Very nice. Just gotta figure out to make it into a <p> instead :)

Comment: @WooDevil If you use wc_print_notice(), you can't. You need to build your own notice custom functionality.

Comment: I know. That is why I asked in this question (still there after you edited it) how to merge them but to make it into a <p> tag instead of notice.

I'll look into making a custom notice.

Comment: @WooDevil Added an addition that will do that (at the end).

Comment: I'm sorry for spamming you, but could you help me in adding seconds as well so that it becomes a countdown timer? Or shall I ask a new question?

Comment: @WooDevil You should ask a new question as a timer involves javascript / jQuery code. But try to find the way yourself before and may be to rethink it a bit.