# WooCommerce Conditional Delivery Notice based on weekdays and time

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, time, days

Based on *[Conditional Delivery Notice based on Time and Date in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062275/conditional-delivery-notice-based-on-time-and-date-in-woocommerce/53069761#53069761)* answer code, I'm trying to display a shipping message with the following lightly modified code:

I try this code without finding the result I hope :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'next_day_delivery' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'next_day_delivery' );

function next_day_delivery() {
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return; // Exit

    // Set the time zone
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

    // From Monday to Thursday
    $is_week_days  = in_array( date('w'), array( 3, 4, 5, 6, 0 ) ) ? true : false;
    $is_monday     = date('w') == 1 ? true : false; // Monday
    $is_tuesday     = date('w') == 2 ? true : false; // Tuesday
    $end_time      = mktime('21', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
    $now_time      = time();
    $after_tomorow = date('l', strtotime('+2 days'));

    $dateDiff      = intval(($end_time - $now_time)/60);
    $diff_hours    = intval($dateDiff/60);
    $diff_minutes  = $dateDiff%60;
    $hours_label   = _n( 'heure', 'heures', $diff_hours, 'wooocommerce' );
    $minutes_label = _n( 'minute', 'minutes', $diff_minutes, 'wooocommerce' );


    if ( $is_monday && $now_time or $is_tuesday && $now_time < $end_time ) {
        // print the information notice
        $message = sprintf( __( '%s left to be delivered tomorrow!', 'woocommerce' ),
        $diff_hours.' '.$hours_label.' and '.$diff_minutes.' '.$minutes_label);
    }
        elseif ( $end_time <= $now_time && $is_week_days ) {
        $message = sprintf( __( 'Your order will be delivered this %s.', 'woocommerce' ), $after_tomorow );
    } else {
        $message = __( 'Your order will be prepared and shipped next upcoming monday and delivered on tuesday.', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    wc_print_notice( $message, 'success' );
}
```

But I cannot make it work for my needs…

We deliver our product each thursday, friday and saturday in different local pickups. So I'd like to have the delivery message that uses the following logic :

- the orders made each week before tuesday 9pm (21h00 in TimeZone Europe/Paris), it should say  "%s left to be delivered from thursday !"
- the orders made each week after tuesday 9pm (21h00 in TimeZone Europe/Paris), it should say  "Your order will be prepared and shipped from next upcoming wednesday and delivered from next thursday."

Any help will be very much appreciated.